# Dual Boot Partitions__To which partition with Linux I should add the free space

Tags: partitioning

My computer has an unallocated free space of 3.69 GB according to Gparted in Ubuntu. Ubuntu is running out of space. I want to add that unallocated space of 3.69 Gb to the Ubuntu. My problem is that when I type a command line in the terminal in Ubuntu I get `/dev/sda5` to `8` with Linux. Already, I know it is not `/dev/sda6`. To which one do I add this unallocated free space ??

Please check the graphics if that helps.

[image: GParted screenshot]

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (>100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I think images are mostly fine. Sometimes there's no way to give us some of the information as "text files, dialog messages, or program output". I know this is a bigger deal for you, but you're expending a lot of energy telling folks about not putting images into their questions... relax :-)

Comment: @heynnema: Oh, I don't mean the nice looking partition diagrams. Those are quite helpful. I mean the textual terminal stuff in the middle image.

Answer (score 3):

Your real problem is that you've got a smallish hard disk. Your sda1 Windows partition consumes most of the space on the disk. If sda1 can be reduced, or eliminated, then we can increase the size of your remaining partitions, as they're all too small.

Let me know, and I can outline the specific steps to take.

edit:

## step #1

- make sure you have a **bootable** Windows install/repair **DVD**
- make sure you have a **bootable** Ubuntu Live **DVD** for your **current version of Ubuntu**
- **make backups of ALL of your important data on BOTH Windows and Ubuntu**

## step #2

in Windows...

- go to the Power control panel
- click on `change what the power buttons do`
- click on `change settings that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast start`
- close power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off`
- type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve to run at reboot time
- reboot Windows
- confirm how much free space that you have on the C: drive, and update your question on AU with that information

in Ubuntu...

- reboot into Ubuntu, or Ubuntu Live DVD
- obtain a **new** screenshot of `gparted` view of `/dev/sda`, and update your question on AU with that new image *(you can replace the old image if you wish)*

## step #3 (pending)

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  Sure, sda1 can be reduced. Let say 20 gb would be freed. What would be those steps ??  I hope they are not too difficult.

Comment: Please start comments to me with `@heynnema` or I may not see them. Reducing sda1 by 20G really isn't enough. How much free space do you have on your C: drive? Please explain what's on your sda8, sda5, and sda7 partitions. It's unusual to have so many partitions for Ubuntu. They are all too small. I've begun to outline the steps you need to do for this process. Do steps #1 and #2. And yes... all of this can be difficult.

Comment: ps: there are 2 ways to reset your Ubuntu partitions. One way is somewhat complicated, and still leaves you with **3 messy Ubuntu partitions**. The other way is somewhat easier, and leaves you with **2 clean Ubuntu partitions**, but it involves reinstalling Ubuntu after we make space. Comments?